Правильность оформления прямой речи и деления текста на абзацы
Этот фрагмент текста взят из рассказа, опубликованного на Проза.ру . Взят неслучайно — меня заинтересовало мнение автора о грамотном письме:
Ps. Однажды, посмотрев детский мультик про запятые 
(казнить нельзя помиловать), все теперь друг друга 
тыкают этой фразой! Хотя по сути, всё гораздо 
сложнее: при прочтении человек создаёт в голове 
внутренний монолог, который порождает визуальные 
образы, запахи, звуки! Мы можем вполне правильно 
интерпретировать содержание исходя из контекста, 
даже если запятые вовсе отсутствуют, или поставлены 
неверно! Можем подобно актёрам дубляжа смещать 
акценты и ударения, представлять разные голоса 
разных персонажей! И Вы хотите сказать, что если я 
не поставил запятую - то это катастрофа? 

Я не оправдываю собственную неграмотность (нужно 
было в своё время лучше зубрить)! Просто иногда 
устаю от людей, которые цепляются к частностям, и 
будто не хотят видеть общую картину.

Отрывок из рассказа
Эта ситуация, должна была заставить задуматься, но я твёрдо решил что хочу стать профессиональным певцом. Поэтому на очередном вокальном уроке я объявил Тамаре Георгиевне, что собираюсь поступать в музыкальное училище.
— И зачем тебе это нужно? — она строго посмотрела на меня.
— Я хочу стать певцом, и заниматься именно пением.
— Но ты же уже почти выучился на кондитера, а петь ты и так сможешь  после работы.
— Нет, я не хочу всю жизнь месить тесто, печь пирожки и прочее. Ведь петь куда интереснее! Я хочу заниматься только пением. А чтобы работать певцом, наверняка нужен диплом.
— Да, конечно, профессионалу диплом не помешает. Но послушай, ведь нет гарантии что всё удачно сложится. Ты даже не представляешь сколько певцов, не стали тем кем хотели стать! Сколько сломанных судеб, сколько депрессии, алкоголизма, или даже самоубийств...
Ты уверен, что готов и хочешь идти по этому пути? Что даже в случай неудачи ты не сломаешься?
Молодой, сильный, самоуверенный широкоплечий парень, с длинными волосами, каким был я в свои 19 лет — с гордой решимостью, ответил, — Да! Уверен!
И поймав её неодобрительный взгляд, повторил — Точно уверен!
Как грамотно записать этот текст?
P.S. Нужно ли это самому автору и его читателям? Стиль текста вроде бы неплохой,  а грамотное письмо изучать, может быть, уже поздно?

А что именно вам не нравится здесь? Если не считать пропуск пару запятых?

Мне много чего не нравится.  1. Это диалог, который прерывается авторской речью. Надо отличать слова автора (атрибуцию) от такой авторской речи. И абзацы оформлены неверно. 2. Фрагмент "Молодой, сильный,..." нужно записать как-то иначе (определения разного вида). 3. Пара запятых? Я так не думаю.  Автор занимается музыкой и знает, что такое музыкальная грамота и нотные знаки. А почему он к речевой грамотности относится так небрежно? Знаки русской пунктуации — это тоже нотные знаки, причем  в прямом смысле.

Запятые поставлены наугад, и от чтения такого текста у меня возникает чувство дискомфорта. А автор рассчитывает на внутренний монолог, который должен порождать «визуальные образы, запахи, звуки!» Тогда надо уделить время и ознакомиться с культурой письма хотя бы в самом общем виде.  // Есть у него еще такое выражение: работать певцом. Вам нравится? Пусть почитает kartaslov.ru/сочетаемость-слова/певец Пример: Я вот, когда совсем маленький был, мечтал стать известным певцом. Обычно перед существительным стоит определение. А так уши почему-то режет...)

Работать певцом у него я не увидел. А в целом текст написан неплохо, не считая пропуск знаков препинания. Ну это дело исправимое. Видимо, начинающий писатель.

Пропуск знаков препинания, лишние знаки... У него много чего написано, кроме того, он не единственный. Когда появился Интернет и стало возможным публиковать свои произведения, народ потянулся в литературу.  И в результате появилось огромное информационное пространство со своими законами и идеалами. Трудно сказать, как много там действительно талантливых людей, легко ли им найти своего читателя.  И вот многие из них, как мне думается, скептически относятся  к правилам орфографии и зубрить их не намерены.  А чем закончится это противостояние, я не знаю.

@Серж Второй раз Вы — о пропуске... ведь и нехватка тоже! Или минус на минус — плюс? А что такое Ps., как можно тыкать друг друга фразой, и сколько же у нас (у друзей) депрессии, алкоголизма? Это же авторская речь... Если не казнить, то точно не миловать.

Согласна с вами.  В  небольшом фрагменте – с десяток отсутствующих запятых и с десяток лишних, нарушены все возможные правила. Текст написан пр принципу: содержание понятно, несколько запятых стоит, так что же еще нужно?  А нужно, чтобы в литературном произведении было все прекрасно: и содержание, и форма. Почему-то наши классики обращали внимание и на каждое слово, и на каждую запятую.

Sharon, какие могут требования к начинающему писателю? Вы чересчур строги. Я не стал бы утверждать, что запятые поставлены наугад. Автору нужно подучиться. Работать певцом - в данном контексте абсолютно нормально. Для автора  - это работа.

Почему бы вам не написать автору?

@shampar
Часть " Сколько сломанных судеб, сколько депрессии, алкоголизма, или даже самоубийств... '' нужно править, да, стилистически она неудачна. Но не более того. Но я чувствую какой-то упрек в вашем тоне. Что не так с этой фразой?

@Серж Писать ему мне не хочется: пользы не будет, а только обидится. Эти авторы очень самолюбивые, меня там с трудом терпят (русскому языку нас тут учите!).   Правила письма для них как дамоклов меч,  они мешают свободному творчеству.  Да и нам часто приходится отказываться от выразительного оборота речи, потому что не помним, как его правильно записать.

@Серж Упрёк? Он сам себе немой упрёк. Пишет безобразно, потому что раньше терпеть не мог читать других, а теперь — себя. Нужно править, пишете? Как же править, коль он читать не может?

Не нужно портить этот текст, он шикарен и неповторим сам по себе такой, какой есть.


Спасибо за ответ, голос от меня. Смешные картинки) Значит, вам все нравится? Пусть народ идет в литературу, в чем есть) Это тоже идея! Я об этом не подумала. Портрет эпохи!  Запятые тогда тоже не надо править?

А это про певцов, нелегкая у них жизнь)  https://yandex.ru/video/preview/15718532601565651883

@Sharon вообще ничего не надо, это же портрет правдивый автора. А вообще, я читаю текст, а он у меня в голове распадается но не на "визуальные
образы, запахи, звуки", а точнее на штампы и мемы, очень странный текст, в котором все настолько прямо банально и плохо, что даже хорошо. Ну вот что делать, если есть поколение у которого в голове одни картинки какие-то плоские, комиксы, с вот такими вот диалогами? Пытаться править? Зачем?

Певцов кстати таких, "профессионалов с дипломом", называют певцы ртом.

Кстати, я уже слышала такую оценку, как у вас: все так плохо, что даже нравится) Штампы и мемы? Да, наверное, а как записать этот отрывок художественно?  Наверное, нужно уйти от стенографии, изменить композицию.  Оставить две-три фразы в диалоге, а остальное пересказать. Или дать все это в виде картинок из прошлого.  Ведь автор вспоминает, как начинался его жизненный путь.

@Sharon а зачем менять стилистику, если она полностью передаёт суть. Помните потрет Дориана Грея, там потрет отражал внутренний мир человека. Вот и тут, полное отражение внутреннего мира, зачем что-то менять, текст максимально правдивый. Художественно - не получиться, получиться исказить, добавив красивостей там, где их нет и не было. Да и быть не должно. Получится не художественность - а искусственность и лживость и уйдет весь тот "шарм". Получится художественность от слова "худо".
"Или дать все это в виде картинок из прошлого." - я не уверен, что это картинки, я вижу мемы.

Вот возьмём фразу: "Сколько сломанных судеб, сколько депрессии, алкоголизма, или даже самоубийств... " - так она вся разваливается потому что каждый блок это просто штамп, но все эти штампы вместе - это мем, какой-то апогей примитивизации мышления. Это как когда вы посмотрели кулинарный рецепт, приходите в магазин, а там ничего из этим продуктов нет, и вы начинаете выбирать похожие ингредиенты, которые как вам кажется могут их заменить: вместо батата берёте проросший картофель, вместо багета - вчерашний батон, вместо соуса - мазик самый дешёвый, вместо икры - симуляцию икры....

Затем, с чувством выполненного долга идёте домой и готовите какое-то модное блюдо и снимаете свой фуд блог, с фотками столовской еды. Подписывая их названиями из высокой итальянской кулинарии. Это целая культура такая, я не знаю как она называется, но это прямо вот есть. Это люди с опредёленным типом мышления. "Я не хочу всю жизнь месить тесто..." - хочу петь ртом. Люди которые делают самую ужасную копию и плагиат, но при этом с полной уверенностью говорят о шедевральности своего творения, прибавляя в конце, "это моё личное мнение".

Но человек абсолютно доволён собой и свои "творчеством", ну кто вы такая, зачем критика? Совершенные же люди. Просто представьте эту фразу у Пушкина или Толстого, или какого классика : я не хочу всю жизнь месить тесто... - это же шедевр, они никогда такого не смогли бы не то, что написать, даже подумать. Это какой-то современный антиталант.

Вы очень красноречивы, если по Станиславскому - я вам верю!)) И правда шедевр, да, это совершенные люди. Зачем же их переделывать! Это ошибка – навязывать другим свои идеалы. Мы очень нетолерантны. Вот читаю фантастику – а там в одном мире сосуществуют люди, маги, гномы, гоблины, оборотни т.д.. И особо друг друга не задирают, дружелюбны почти: "Зй, человек, у тебя сигареты есть?" Тогда буду издали наблюдать за совершенными людьми)  P. S.  Может быть, людей тоже надо делить на подвиды?)

@Sharon именно так, не одёргивайте, а наблюдайте и описывайте. Можно таких, каких видите, документально, а можно, помещая их вы вымышленные обстоятельства, художественно. Нельзя переделать мир, можно его правдоподобно отразить. Любому писателю дай такого человека понаблюдать, он из него конфетку, а не персонажа сделает. Гоголь был бы такому очень рад) даже может быть второй том бы написал - "Мемичные души."

@Sharon кстати, а вы знаете кем в итоге стал наш герой? Он стал учителем пения и преподаёт вокал детям. То есть этот диалог, это прямо разговор с альтер-эго. Так что это целая законченная история, почти миф или баллада, с возвращением к началу.

@Буратино,когда хотите — хорошо пишете и умно размышляете.

@Серж по секрету - я всегда умно размышляю, но не всегда могу это передать) и иногда, слишком умно, так что сам не понимаю, о чём это я)
